# How can I connect to a Jabber chat room within Google Chat?

Tags: gmail, chat, xmpp

I use the chat client in Gmail.  Recently a Jabber chat server was set up at work, and I'd like to connect to it.  How do I set that up?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that your entry in $HOME/.centerim/config matches this example.

```
jab_nick        yourGmailAddress@gmail.com
jab_pass        yourPlaintextPassword
jab_server      talk.google.com:5223
jab_prio        4
jab_ssl         1
jab_status      o
```

Source: http://www.centerim.org/index.php/CenterIM4_Frequently_Asked_Questions

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail web client does not have an interface for joining chat rooms on other federated servers, and you cannot simply add the address of a chat channel (e.g. `jabber@conference.jabber.org`) as a contact (at least within the Gmail web client). So you would need to set up some kind of relay to accomplish this. However, this probably defeats the whole purpose of using the simple web chat interface in Gmail for you.

<strike>Alternatively, if you require a web-based solution for joining a xmpp chat room, [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/) supports Jabber conferences.</strike> (Meebo products are no longer available).